# Error class Mage_Sintax_Helper_Data not found while opening the admin

Tags: ce-1.6.2.0

In my magento CE 1.6.2.0 i am getting this error suddenly actually i was trying to develop an extension which is not activated yet.

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Sintax_Helper_Data' not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php on line 516

I have tried finding it o Google but no luck :'( any body having any idea about it.

Answer (score 3):

This mostly happens when you call a helper that's not defined - Magento then assumes the default `Mage` namespace.

You can search the code of your extension for any references to the `sintax` helper. This can be direct references like `Mage::helper('sintax')` or `$this->helper('sintax')` or less obvious ones in your xml files (config.xml, system.xml or any layout update files) using the `module` attribute, like:

```
<config>
    <tabs>
        <catalog translate="label" module="catalog">
             <label>Catalog</label>
             <sort_order>200</sort_order>
        </catalog>
    </tabs>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution. The reason to get this error is this extension is  broken extension.

Comment: Viewd 4 times, thanks all for pay your attention to this.

Comment: and what was wrong with it?